# react-router Link does not resolve param 2.0.0-rc5

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I can't get this to work:

```
<Link to={'/items/${this.props.id}'}>{this.props.name}</Link>
```

with this routing config:

```
const routes = <Route path="/" component={App}>
        // default route for '/' path
        <IndexRoute component={Main} />
        <Route path="/items/:id" component={ItemForm} />
    </Route>
```

When clicking on the link, I receive on the ItemForm the literal value ${this.props.id} as parameter.

Using this syntax:

```
<Route name="itemForm" path="/items/:id" component={ManageProcessPageContainer} />
    <Link to="itemForm" params={{ id: "123"}} >{this.props.name}</Link>
```

results in the error

> Warning: [react-router] Location "/itemForm" did not match any routes

How does react-router resolve the $ part here?
Thanks!

Comment: You just don't have an itemForm route. Add one.

Comment: But I have the <Route name="itemForm" ... entry? is that not the itemForm route?

Comment: Wow, I used a " ' " instead of a " ` " in the Link to property... all the difference.

Comment: That one took me some hours

Comment: react-router doesn't use `name` anymore. The links link to urls. So `<Link to={"/items/' + id}`